# SQL count summary per week on multiple tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join

I have a SQL that generates a series of weeks from the past 365 days:

```
SELECT
  to_char(weekdate, 'YYWW') as yearWeek
FROM
GENERATE_SERIES(
  NOW()::DATE-EXTRACT(DOW FROM NOW())::INTEGER-365,
  NOW()::DATE-EXTRACT(DOW from NOW())::INTEGER,
  '1 week'
) AS t(weekdate)
```

I then join on a summary of counts per week from a 'team_a' table using a timestamp column ("LEFT OUTER JOIN" takes into account weeks with 0 counts):

```
SELECT
  to_char(weekdate, 'YYWW') as yearWeek,
  count(a.timestamp) AS team_a_total
FROM
GENERATE_SERIES(
  NOW()::DATE-EXTRACT(DOW FROM NOW())::INTEGER-365,
  NOW()::DATE-EXTRACT(DOW from NOW())::INTEGER,
  '1 week'
) AS t(weekdate)
LEFT OUTER JOIN team_a a
  ON to_char(weekdate, 'YYWW') = to_char(a.timestamp, 'YYWW')
GROUP BY to_char(weekdate, 'YYWW')
ORDER BY yearWeek
```

This works fine and results as expected BUT I would like to join another summary of counts from a 'team_b' table and I thought it was a simple case of adding another "LEFT OUTER JOIN" like so:

```
SELECT
  to_char(weekdate, 'YYWW') as yearWeek,
  count(a.timestamp) AS team_a_total,
  count(b.timestamp) AS team_b_total
FROM
GENERATE_SERIES(
  NOW()::DATE-EXTRACT(DOW FROM NOW())::INTEGER-365,
  NOW()::DATE-EXTRACT(DOW from NOW())::INTEGER,
  '1 week'
) AS t(weekdate)
LEFT OUTER JOIN team_a a
  ON to_char(weekdate, 'YYWW') = to_char(a.timestamp, 'YYWW')
LEFT OUTER JOIN team_b b
  ON to_char(weekdate, 'YYWW') = to_char(b.timestamp, 'YYWW')
GROUP BY to_char(weekdate, 'YYWW')
ORDER BY yearWeek
```

But the results are not correct. The 'team_a_total' and 'team_b_total' columns seem to show the multiplication of both columns

For example, for week '1628' (2016 week 28), it should be a total of 8 for 'team_a_total' and 36 for 'team_b_total' but both columns are showing a result of 288 which is 8x36.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for the answers. Based on Laurenz's code, this is what worked for me (as well as Hambone's answer):

```
---------------------------
SELECT weekdate,
  team_a_total,
  count(b.timestamp) AS team_b_total
FROM
(
  SELECT
    to_char(weekdate, 'YYWW') AS weekdate,
    count(a.timestamp) AS team_a_total
  FROM
  GENERATE_SERIES(
    NOW()::DATE-EXTRACT(DOW FROM NOW())::INTEGER-365,
    NOW()::DATE-EXTRACT(DOW from NOW())::INTEGER,
    '1 week'
  ) AS t(weekdate)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN team_a a ON to_char(a.timestamp, 'YYWW') = to_char(weekdate, 'YYWW')
  GROUP BY to_char(weekdate, 'YYWW')
) subq
LEFT OUTER JOIN team_b b ON to_char(b.timestamp, 'YYWW') = weekdate
GROUP BY weekdate, team_a_total
ORDER BY weekdate
---------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think some subqueries might fix it:

```
with a as (
  select
    to_char(timestamp, 'YYWW') as week,
    count (*) as cnt
  from team_a
  group by week
),
b as (
  select
    to_char(timestamp, 'YYWW') as week,
    count (*) as cnt
  from team_b
  group by week
),
s as (
  SELECT
    to_char(weekdate, 'YYWW') as yearWeek
  FROM
  GENERATE_SERIES(
    NOW()::DATE-EXTRACT(DOW FROM NOW())::INTEGER-365,
    NOW()::DATE-EXTRACT(DOW from NOW())::INTEGER,
    '1 week'
  ) AS t(weekdate)
)
SELECT
  s.yearWeek,
  coalesce (a.cnt, 0) as team_a_total,
  coalesce (b.cnt, 0) as team_b_total
FROM
  s
  LEFT JOIN a on s.yearWeek = a.week
  left join b on s.yearWeek = b.week
ORDER BY s.yearWeek
```

The issue is you had a mini-Cartesian join going, where you were joining every record from `team_a` for that week by every record in `team_b` for the same week.

So, if you had this:

```
   team_a              team_b
   1633    x           1633       a
   1633    y           1633       b
   1633    z
```

The join you had would produce six records.

```
x-a
x-b
y-a
y-b
z-a
z-c
```

By isolating them in subqueries, you can aggregate them and then join on the aggregated results.

The subquery `s` wasn't precisely necessary, but I thought it made it look cleaner.

Comment: That almost works apart from a couple of typo's: "series as" => "s as" and "a.cnt as team_b_total" => "b.cnt as team_b_total". Also, the results show blank/null for weeks with no counts; how to change those to 0's instead?

Comment: Yeah -- good catch on the typos.  I think I fixed that.  Also, to get the zero instead of a null, use `coalesce`.  I edited my answer with all three of those items (typos + coalesce).

Answer (score 1):

The logical order of execution is: first join, then filter, then group, then order.

After the first join, you get multiple rows for one week (grouping is not done yet), and if you add a second join, each of these rows is joined to the new table. So you end up with the product.

One way to do it is to use a subquery to force the first `GROUP BY` to be performed before the second join:

```
SELECT weekdate,
       team_a_total,
       count(b.timestamp) AS team_b_total
FROM (
        SELECT to_char(weekdate, 'YYWW') AS weekdate,
               count(a.timestamp) AS team_a_total
        FROM ... t(weekdate)
           LEFT OUTER JOIN team_a ON ...
        GROUP BY to_char(weekdate, 'YYWW')
     ) subq
   LEFT OUTER JOIN team_b ON ...
GROUP BY weekdate, team_a_total
ORDER BY weekdate;
```

Comment: Very good and thanks for explaining the reason for the unexpected outcome due to the sequence of events in the SQL.